# Looking for a specific character in a list of strings

Tags: python

Lets say I have a list of with these strings in it:

```
list = ["Cat", "Bag?", "Dog", "?Duck"]
```

How would I print out only the words containing a question mark?

Example output:

```
Bag? contains a question mark
?Duck contains a question mark
```

Comment: you should post at least the code you have tried. You will need to use an `if` and likely an `in` to check if the question mark is in the word........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't name your variable "list".  That aside, the following would work.  Simply use the "in" keyword

```
list1 = ["Cat", "Bag?", "Dog", "?Duck"]

for i in list1:
    if "?" in i:
        print(i + " contains a question mark")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `in` like this:

```
a = ['hi', 'hi?']
for i in a:
    if '?' in i:
        print(i+' contins a question mark')
```

Output:

```
hi? contins a question mark
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try and iterate through each word. Then in each word, I'd iterate through that. If I find a letter, say a "?" then i'll print the word.

```
your_list = ["?adsd","dsasd"]
for words in your_list:
    for every_letter in words:
        if every_letter == '?':
            print(words)
```

**list comprehension**

````
words_similar = [words for words in your_list for every_letter in words if every_letter == '?']```
````

Answer (score -1):

```
list = ["Cat", "Bag?", "Dog", "?Duck"]
for i in list:
    if '?' in i:
        print(i, "contains a question mark")
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
my_list = ["Cat", "Bag?", "Dog", "?Duck"]
print('\n'.join(f'{word} contains a question mark' for word in my_list  if '?' in word))
```

Note that I

- renamed `list` to `my_list` as `list` is a built-in class in python and overriding it is bad practice
- used `in` as pointed out by Brian and Chris
- used list comprehension to avoid the need for `if`-clauses as in some of the other answers

Comment: That is far too complicated for someone trying to just learn how to print strings with a certain character in them

Comment: They can try & understand my answer after understanding yours, though, and that way expand their python skills :)

Answer (score -1):

```
for string in list:
    if "?" in string:
         echo string + "contains a question mark"
```